# Change the value of an input field just before form submit but do not display in UI ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have some html controls like TextBox, Text Areas in my page. The requirement is like this: Whenever user enters any value in these fields I want to append a "special character" value at the end of the input string. I have tried this using jquery which works but the moment the value is changed it gets displayed to the user which is undesirable.

```
$(".wildCardSearch").each(function () {
                var searchValueWC = $(this).val();
                if (searchValueWC.trim()) {
                    $(this).val('%' + searchValueWC + '%');
                }
            });
```

Yes, That right i want the value to get changed in the request (Httppost) to the server without getting the change displayed to the end user. Is that possible?
FYI, I am using ASP.net controls and due to some constraints i do not want to make this change in the server side controls. I want jquery to perform this operation whenever any controls with a particular css class is added.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use a new variable and use that for further process. Like this:

```
$(".wildCardSearch").each(function () {
    var searchValueWC = $(this).val();
    if (searchValueWC.trim()) {
       var newValue = $(this).val('%' + searchValueWC + '%');
    }
    //now use newValue
});
```

Comment: Using a new variable wont serve this purpose. Unfortunately I have to change the value of the control only as my server side logic is written as per the control value which i cannot change.